# Changing text depending on current time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've only had a very quick preliminary search but is it possible to automatically change a specific element with javascript or jquery  depending on the time?.. or by the local time of the computer who is viewing the webpage.

For instance say I have a `<h2>Good Morning</h2>` display before 12pm, and then automatically it would change to to `<h2>Good Afternoon</h2>` once it gets past this time.

I honestly, have not looked very deep into at all, but just wondering if this possible,
and if so, is there a particular plugin that would aide me with this/what is the best way to do it?

Comment: [.getHours()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp) and [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Yes it is possible and you don't need any plugins. You just need to check the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) on the `Date` object in javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't need jQuery.

```
document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = new Date().getHours() >= 12 ? 'Good Afternoon' : 'Good Morning';
```

Comment: By the way, for the pure text there is `.textContent`. It's a little bit more logical there than `.innerHTML`

Comment: 15 years of web development and I've never used or seen `.textContent` in a code base before ;)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's `Date` object is you best bet to get the time.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Once you know the time, it's easy to change the text in the header.

Answer (score 0):

The text changes, might be done using cron job , if it is possible , you can do it just add or activate the css for the same element.